# Как парсить в PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser тег <title> в <head>

Tags: php, html, парсер, dom, simple-html-dom

Не получается парсить head теги...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790625/getting-title-of-page-using-simple-html-dom):

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file('http://www.google.com');
$titleraw = $html->find('title',0);
$title = $titleraw->innertext;
```

Comment: Не работает, не выводит информацию  echo $title->plaintext; Например <title>Яндекс </title>

Comment: Обновил с проверкой